# Multiple highcharts in one container in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, highcharts, vuetify.js

I've been trying to put multiple highcharts into one container but I can't seem to find any examples on how to do it. I'm absurdly new to Vuejs, and I've been trying to read all the resources I can about this but I can't really find a way of making it work.

The chart looks like this:

```
<template>
  <highcharts :options="options"></highcharts>
</template>

<script>

import HighchartsVue from 'highcharts-vue'

import Highcharts from 'highcharts'

import highchartsMore from 'highcharts/highcharts-more'

Vue.use(HighchartsVue)

highchartsMore(Highcharts)

export default {
  props: ['options'],
  data() {
return {
}
  }
}
</script>
```

My main component looks like this:

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid text-xs-center style="height: 90vh; max-height: 100%;">
     <v-layout row wrap>
      <v-flex xs2>
          <v-card flat>
              <Chart :options="chartOptions"/>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>
<script>

import Chart from '../components/Chart.vue'

var testdata = [
          // each slice of the pie gets its own color
          { y: 40, color: '#1DACE8', name: 'test1' },
          { y: 70, color: '#1C366B', name: 'test2' },
          { y: 55, color: '#F24D29', name: 'test3' },
          { y: 53, color: '#E5C4A1', name: 'test4' },
          { y: 95, color: '#C4CFD0', name: 'test5' }
        ]

var testdata2 = [
          // each slice of the pie gets its own color
          { y: 10, color: '#1DACE8', name: '1' },
          { y: 30, color: '#1C366B', name: '2' },
          { y: 45, color: '#F24D29', name: '3' },
          { y: 93, color: '#E5C4A1', name: '4' },
          { y: 15, color: '#C4CFD0', name: '5' }
        ]

export default {
  name: 'chartapp2',
  components: {
  Chart
  },

  data() {
    return {
      chartOptions:{
        chart: {
          polar: true,
          backgroundColor: '#F5F5F5'
},
        exporting: {
            buttons: {
                contextButton: {
                    theme: {
            fill:"#F5F5F5"
        }
                }
            }
        },
title: {
    text: 'City 1'
},

subtitle: {
    text: 'Railacc stuff'
},

pane: {
    startAngle: -22.5},

xAxis: {
    tickInterval: 45,
    min: 0,
    max: 360,
    labels: false
},

yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    tickInterval: 1,
    labels: false
},

plotOptions: {
    series: {
        pointStart: 0,
        pointInterval: 45
    },
    column: {
        pointPadding: 0,
        groupPadding: 0,
        colorByPoint: true
    }
},

tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.y, this.point.name;
            }
        },

series: [{
    type: 'column',
    name: '',
    data: testdata,
    pointPlacement: 'between'
},
{
    type: 'column',
    name: '2',
    data: testdata2,
    pointPlacement: 'between'
}]
      },
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

In theory this should work, but all I see is one chart instead of 2 in one single container.
Any idea on how to make this work?

EDIT: The idea would be to have something like this https://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo. Basically where there's only one legend for the two plots.
Instead of having two series in one graph, or two graphs. I would like to split the series into two series in two different graphs.

Comment: What do you mean saying "Multiple Highcharts in one container"? Because there can be only one chart per container. Here is your chart reproduced in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Ln0yk8wz/. You have defined two series and the same is on the chart. Could you describe more precisely what do you want to achive?

Comment: @WojciechChmiel I've added an example. It doesn't necessarily have to be with two different charts but one graph container has one legend and it can include multiple series. Having several graphs in one container, means that you can add multiple graphs with only one legend for example.

Comment: Do you mean something like this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nyhtfz0g/? I've added a second y-axis below the first one and displayed two series parallelly.

Comment: It works perfectly. Unfortunately something goes wrong when using the polar tag. https://jsfiddle.net/6tjh5re1/.

Comment: The polar will not work with multiple axes. However, you can achieve it by adding a second chart which will be controlled by the first chart legend. Check the example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qndeho5u/

Answer (score 0):

try in series array use

```
center: ['25%', '50%'],
```

params which will describe chart centers positions

Comment: I removed the link as it was adding confusion. My problem isn't with the spacing but with the fact that I can't even include the several charts in one container.